# in_array() returning false, although I'm sure the needle is in the haystack

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a bizarre problem with `in_array`. For some reason it's returning false on what I'm sure should return true.

The only reason I can think it's doing this is if there's a hidden character or something which I can't see. But I haven't added anything like this while using the variable.

**Screen shot of output:**

[image: Output]

**`isValidAnswer` method:**

```
    /**
     * Return whether this is a valid answer or not
     * 
     * @param mixed $answer
     * @return boolean $validAnswer
     */
    public function isValidAnswer($answer) {
        print($answer . "<br />"); print_r($this->answers);
        return in_array($answer, $this->answers);
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump` instead of `print_r`.

Comment: Canyou  give the details from where th message "Error:Invalid answer" is comming. I mean the code..

Comment: Please reference my answer; this has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

From what is displayed here, your code is fine.

Your explanation with the characters is possible.

Your question does not show the acutal return value of the function. Only 'Error: invalid answer'. Maby the error is where you pick up the return value?

The following code outputs

```
No<br />Array
(
    [0] => Yes
    [1] => No
    [2] => Maybe
    [3] => 
)
bool(true)
```

..

```
<?

class Test {

     private $answers = array('Yes','No','Maybe','');

    /**
     * Return whether this is a valid answer or not
     * 
     * @param mixed $answer
     * @return boolean $validAnswer
     */


    public function isValidAnswer($answer) {
        print($answer . "<br />"); print_r($this->answers);
        return in_array($answer, $this->answers);
    }
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test->isValidAnswer('No'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help but I believe I've resolved my own issue.

**In the construct for the class I've added this code:**

```
$this->answers = unserialize($pollData['answers']); // Unserialise the answers

foreach ($this->answers as $key=>$var) { // Ensure there's no hidden characters or whitespace
        preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', "", $this->answers[$key]);
        $this->answers[$key] = trim($this->answers[$key]);
}
```

There was some white space, and I believe a carriage return left in there. So this code in the construct should ensure from now on that it's in a "clean" format. And it's now returning true.

I also need to take a look and make sure that it's cleaned before it goes into the database.

Thank you for your help however.

Answer (score 1):

problem is in your array `$this->answers`. it's really very tough to find where is the problem. So You can try to `redefine` your array. I have also tried this one for below two

```
1) $answers = array("Yes","No","Maybe","");

2) $answers=array("Yes","No","Maybe","");
```

point `1` not works but point `2` works fine.

I have wrote the below for testing

```
function isValidAnswer($val) 
{
    $answers=array("Yes","No","Maybe","");
    //print_r($answers);
    if(in_array($val,$answers))
    {
        echo $val;
    }

}


isValidAnswer('No');
```